# wrap-function, wrap-raf, contextual-ee affixing on web pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am experiencing a strange behavior on my website. I recently found on webmaster tools that, it found crawl error 404 for many webpages on my website. I could not understand how these pages are created because all of the 404 pages contains these few words at the end

> wrap-function, contextual-ee, wrap-events, wrap-raf, wrap-timer, wrap-xhr

The pages are created by affixing one of these word at the end of normal working pages.

For example the 404 pages are:

> mywebsite.com/normalpage1/wrap-funcion
>
> mywebsite.com/nromalpage2/wrap-event
>
> mywebsite.com/normalpage3/wrap-timer

I am using Wordpress self hosted blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you guys using New Relic? In my case, all these paths seem to be referenced to in New Relic's JavaScript string to measure page load time. Certainly a new thing, it started happening last week (possibly after New Relic agent upgrade).

Comment: Yes, I am using New Relic and upgraded last week. I will check their documentation.

Answer (score 13):

An update to the Browser agent was released yesterday afternoon which contained a fix for this issue. For URLs that have already been crawled, it may it may take some time for the bot to stop attempting to crawl them, but it will eventually resolve on its own.

To confirm that your site is running the latest version, please search for "372.min.js" in the HTML source. If you have currently running application agents, you may need to restart these agents for the change to be picked up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the reply from New Relic:

> We understand that the 404s you're seeing can look concerning. This is
>   caused by an issue with the Google crawler where it tries to follow
>   links in Javascript. Google strives to detect these types of issues
>   and resolve them, and typically this type of issue shouldn't affect
>   your site's search performance, according to the Google Webmaster
>   Tools help: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1154698.
>
> Our engineers are investigating the best way to address this issue
>   since we understand it is a concern for many of our customers. We
>   should have a fix developed soon which will resolved these issues.
>
> If you have any other questions on this, please let us know.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Andy New Relic Support

Comment: This has been corrected now, but in most cases you need to restart your app for update to take effect.